# ng-bind-html blank the page when binding data change

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I was trying to achieve something like Quora's read on feature where when expanded more content will be displayed.

I am using ng-bind-html binding an html page into P element.

```
<p ng-show="viewModel.level==0" ng-bind-html="viewModel.content0 | sanitize">
<p ng-show="viewModel.level==1" ng-bind-html="viewModel.content1 | sanitize">
```

the expanding works fine, but when collapse from level 1 to 0 (more content to less), the html page went into blank stuck there until you click or drag the page.

how to avoid that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer by accident.

what I need is a notification that the list size has changed:

```
$scope.$broadcast('scroll.resize');
```